# randomly assign m number to n bins

Tags: sas

I'm looking for an efficient way to assign m distinct numbers (1 to m) to n bins (m>>n).

Say m = 20, n = 3, what I need is `1, 3, 5` or `19, 15, 2`. It looks like sampling without replacement from m numbers.

Currently I use `proc surveyselect` to subset `n` rows from `m` rows and then transpose it. But how can I quickly generate `k` such samples? Ultimately the output should be (given `m=20,n=3`, sample size `k=4`)

```
2,5,9
12,2,10
5,2,4
9,2,1
```

And is there a way to avoid generating duplicates in output samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want duplicates it seems like you are asking for a sample of n*k from m grouped by n into k groups.

```
%let m=20;
%let n=3;
%let k=4;
proc plan;
   factors m=%eval(&n*&k) of &m random n=1 of &n cyclic;
   output out=sample;
   quit;
data sampleV / view=sampleV;
   set sample;
   if n eq 1 then k+1;
   run;
proc transpose data=sampleV out=sample2(drop=_:) prefix=n;
   by k;
   var m;
   id n;
   run;
```